# IPMI graceful shutdown before `power cycle` when executing with ipmitool?

Tags: ipmi, ipmitool

I have many servers that sometimes require the entire server to be cold started due to certain changes.

We have many servers so this all is automated.

Right now, if the process requires a cold start, the task runs `ipmitool power cycle` locally on the host to give it a full cold restart.

This hasn't been a problem, but I can see it being an issue in the future since there is no attempt at a graceful shutdown. I know there is IPMI `power soft` so it would be nice if there is a way to combine `power soft` and then `power cycle` after the soft power down completes OR a timeout elapses.

**Is this possible at all?** I realize I could do this externally by executing `power soft`, monitoring, then running a separate `power cycle`, but that would require connecting to ipmi remotely which is out of scope for this current automation.

Comment: did you done at first the usual things like, update the software, Firmware etc? I mean it could also be a nasty old crappy firmware/Software Bug

Comment: Automated with what? Where is your code?

Comment: @symcbean Ansible, literally just running `ipmi power cycle` (which is in the original post) as a command task but that doesn't change the context or meaning of the question at all. This question is about ipmi behavior.

Comment: You know you can powercycle the server from the remote one using `ipmitool` there, right ? For obvious reason you cannot powerdown and then powercycle certain cerver locally so do it remotely using the same `ipmitool` and the network access to the target IPMI. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to use just a single command for that? Sequence like that

```
CREDS="-H <host> -U <user> -P <passwd> -I lanplus"
ipmitool $CREDS power soft
while [ $(ipmitool $CREDS power status)="on" ]; do 
  sleep 1
done
ipmitool power on
```

will do what you need imho. Of course some timeout should be taken into account to ensure rebooting if OS hangs.